# Remove managedObject arbitrary fragments

Tags: cumulocity

I plan to use custom JSON fragments to hold domain data on my managed objects.

When we create an object via the API we'll attach a fragment with metadata that defines it according to our model.

It's straightforward to create and update these fragments but it seems there is no way to remove a fragment without deleting the entire managedObject, this is impractical as, for example, we'd lose all the measurements for that object.

I guess this isn't big problem as I can simply set an empty fragment and handle that in my parsing code, but it'd be useful to be able to delete these fragments should we need to in future, is there a way to do this that I didn't work out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update a fragment with null. This will remove the fragment.

```
PUT /inventory/managedObjects/{id} HTTP/1.1
Host: {tenant}.cumulocity.com
Authorization: Basic ....
Content-Type: application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.managedObject+json
Accept: application/vnd.com.nsn.cumulocity.managedObject+json

{
    "myFragment": null
}
```